# Confused about if condition CPP

Tags: c++

Confused about if condition, how does it executes following statements.

```
if(1 && (1 || 0) != 0)  or  if(1 || (1 && 0) != 0)
```

In above if statement what is the sequence of executing/validating the statements.
(left to right or right to left)  if left to right, then if first argument/expression is true does it evaluates 2nd expression/argument? is it true for both the logical AND and OR operators.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logical `&&` short circuits if the first operand evaluates to `false` (because `false && x` is `false` for all x)

Logical `||`  short circuits if the first operand evaluates to `true` (because `true || x` is `true` for all x)

They both evaluate left-to-right.

Comment: I would also note that `!=` has higher precedence than both `&&` and `||` and thus the difference is computed *before* applying either `&&` or `||` to the result.

Answer (score 1):

It's left to right

1. First executes 1. Then executes `(1 || 0) != 0`. To do that it executes 1 || 0 -> true, so the whole thing is true.
2. First executes 1 - it's true, so it short circuits and returns true.

Answer (score 0):

It's left to right. || short-circuits if first expression is true, && if first expression is false.

Answer (score 0):

Both things are fundamentally different go read **D Morgans Laws**!s

Answer (score 0):

lets break it down step-by-step:

`(1 || 0)` becomes `true` as 1 short-circuits the expression

so `(1 || 0) != 0` is `true`

`1 && true` is true by the definition of the logical && operator

`or` is a define/keyword for `||` but the first section is already true, so we short-circuit the expression again and the code inside the `if` block is executed.